# network access issue and triage

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

We have two hosts in same vlan with same route rules.

One of them is able to connect to an outside IP while on another I get `failed: Connection timed out` when testing the connectivity through `netcat`.

I have tried `mtr /traceroute` and it gives me the same results.

Is there a `netcat` command which telnets to a port and gives a verbose output with intermediate hops?

Or you can point me to an issue or triaging commands?

thanks.

Comment: A tool like `tcpdump` is often useful in this sort of situation to inspect the packets leaving from or returning to your system. This behavior could be caused by some sort of filter on the network router.  Verify that the netmask is correct on the problematic system.  If you change the ip address of the system experiencing the problem, does the behavior change?